# converting timestamp date to unix timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp

i have data like this one
date what i got from timestamp utc are : 2020-06-29 05:31:58.153

```
 LocalDateTime timestampasstring = message.getHeader().getUtcTimeStamp( SendingTime.FIELD);
 Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(timestampasstring.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
 System.out.println(timestamp);
 String timestampstrings = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(timestamp);
 String timestampstrings2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(timestamp);
```

i need to get timestamp number like 2020-06-29 05:31:58
and convert it become unix timestamp like this one 1593408718
how to convert it ?

Comment: Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime--

Comment: @ScaryWombat That class should _never_ be used except in actual JDBC code.

Comment: `Date currentDate = new Date();`
`long t = currentDate.getTime()/1000;`

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Agree, somehow with his pre-edted question I made the bad assumption that `Timestamp` is also he had.

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Any wrong result? Please quote. Also what did your search turn up? In what way was it insufficient or didn’t work? [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. You are already using `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Just stick to classes from java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Having read your question, I assume your method `message.getHeader().getUtcTimeStamp(SendingTime.FIELD)` returns a `String` (not a `LocalDateTime`) representing a timestamp in UTC while being formatted either like `2020-06-29 05:31:58.153` or `2020-06-29 05:31:58`.

Since you have (shown) differently formatted datetimes (respectively, datetimes with a different accuracy), you will have to take care of that by defining a suitable `DateTimeFormatter` using a pattern able to deal with optional milliseconds (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]`).

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // receive the result from your message, this is just an example
    String utcTimestamp = "2020-06-29 05:31:58";
    // create a ZonedDateTime by parsing the String to a LocalDateTime and adding a time zone
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(utcTimestamp,
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]"))
                         .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // then get the epoch milliseconds / unix timestamp
    long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(zdt + " ==> " + millis + " epoch millis");
}
```

The output of this is, of course, different for datetimes that are only equal down to seconds:

1. `2020-06-29T05:31:58Z[UTC] ==> 1593408718000` epoch millis
2. `2020-06-29T05:31:58.153Z[UTC] ==> 1593408718153` epoch millis

If you call `long seconds = zdt.toEpochSeconds()` instead of converting `toInstant().toEpochMillis` (and adjust the output a little) you will get the same value for both examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // receive the result from your message, this is just an example
    String utcTimestamp = "2020-06-29 05:31:58.153";
    // create a ZonedDateTime by parsing the String to a LocalDateTime and adding a time zone
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(utcTimestamp,
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]"))
                         .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // then get the epoch seconds
    long seconds = zdt.toEpochSecond();
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(zdt + "\t==>\t" + seconds + " epoch seconds");
}
```

Output:

1. `2020-06-29T05:31:58Z[UTC] ==> 1593408718 epoch seconds`
2. `2020-06-29T05:31:58.153Z[UTC] ==> 1593408718 epoch seconds`

If your method really returns a `LocalDateTime`, you could *simply* skip conversions and write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime utcDateTime = message.getHeader().getUtcTimeStamp(SendingTime.FIELD); 
    // then get the epoch seconds
    long seconds = utcDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toEpochSecond();
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(utcDateTime + "\t==>\t" + seconds + " epoch seconds");
}
```

Comment: yes from my broker there is any millisecond like 2020-06-29 05:31:58.153 but i wanna save without millisecond because if i want to get price from my database i just want to check the second same as my friend

Comment: @yuyukungkung OK, good... see the last edit as well, please...

Answer (score 0):

If your `getUtcTimeStamp` method is helpful enough to return a `LocalDateTime`, you're most of the way there. Convert to an `Instant` using `ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` (your `getUtcTimeStamp` really should be doing this for you if it already knows it's in UTC), then just call `toEpochSecond()` (or `toEpochMilli()` if you want the milliseconds part, but you just showed whole seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine. Here’s my variant. First declare a formatter for parsing:

```
private DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter();
```

Consider declaring the formatter `static` and/or `final`. With this formatter I’d do:

```
    String timestampAsString = "2020-06-29 05:31:58.153";
    
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime
            .parse(timestampAsString, timestampFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    long unixTimestamp = dateTime.toEpochSecond();
    
    System.out.println(unixTimestamp);
```

Output is what you asked for:

> 1593408718

The nice thing about the formatter is that it accepts both `2020-06-29 05:31:58.153` and `2020-06-29 05:31:58`, that is, time both with and without fraction of second, and with any fraction of from 1 up to 9 decimals. Reusing `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` in the formatter buys us this.